# Angular 6 - httpClient does not send get request to certain url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an API build with Lumen which I try to consume via an Angular 6 application.

The following code does not send any request (nothing visible in Chromes DevTools):

```
// This does not work!
// The api entry gets added using an HttpInterceptor

return this.http.get(`/users`).subscribe(
  r => console.log(r),
  e => console.log(e)
);
```

The following code DOES work and sends the correct request to my API:

```
// This DOES work!
// The api entry gets added using an HttpInterceptor

return this.http.get(`/humans`).subscribe(
  r => console.log(r),
  e => console.log(e)
);
```

Both endpoints point to the same controller in lumen.

```
// api.php - routes in Lumen implementation
$router->get('/users', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'UserController@getUsers'
]);

$router->get('/humans', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'UserController@getUsers'
]);
```

I can not figure out why the second route works and the first one doesn't.

EDIT: I can access both api endpoints correctly using Postman. I think the problem is with angular.

Comment: what's the result using a rest client like postman?

Comment: Using Postman `GET https://www.api.example.com/users` and  `GET https://www.api.example.com/humans` are both returning the same (correct) result.

Comment: do you have some interceptor that could make some weird thing?

Comment: I tried disabling all interceptors - it still does not send teh request.

Comment: Try to find where the error is using break points and debugger, the code you have posted here is not enough to solve the issue. Maybe debugging would help to find the error

Comment: maybe you have some errors in console? can you make a working example on stackblitz?

Comment: I went trough the code step by step yesterday. After the "Promise resolved (async)"-barrier a simple error (status 400) emerges. When I check the network tab there is no GET request to be found. I will setup a new installation of Angular 6 and try the same code.

Comment: @Oru error 400 is a bad request error, tipically it means that json structure does not match rest service expected parameters structure

Comment: That is correct - the problem is, that there is no network activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with a **re-install of Angular 6**.
After that I simply copied the code in the app directory and it worked.

I know that it is not a clear solution to the problem.

Thank you for your input.